# How can I determine if a probiotic product has ingredients that will be helpful to a GI illness?

Tags: cats, medicines

My friend has an elderly (female, spayed) cat who has developed a GI problem (diarrhea + scooting).  They are going through all of the veterinary recommended tests and treatments, but while waiting for results the vet suggested some probiotic treats (with the mindset that its unlikely to make things worse and may make things better).

How do we determine if probiotics would be helpful for the cat's condition (are they the right strain, are they alive, etc)? How can my friend determine if his vet is selling him snake oil?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**
Most probiotic product labels are inaccurate and sloppy, but the two notable exceptions (from a 2011 study) were Purina's Fortiflora and IAMS Prostora Max. However, even with adequate labels, the product may not deliver a clinically significant amount of probiotics.

**Details**

A study was published in 2011 (so a few years ago, the products may have changed since then) that attempted to determine if probiotics labels are adequate and accurate. The study did not consider the affect that the probiotics would have on pet health, but concentrated on label claims.

- Weese, JS. Martin H. Assessment of commercial probiotic bacterial contents and label accuracy. Canadian Veterinary Journal 2011;52:43–46. ([full text](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3003573/pdf/cvj_01_43.pdf))

First, labels were assessed for adequacy. This meant:

> Product labels were scrutinized; this included an assessment  of
>   spelling of contents, if contents were clearly described (genus  and
>   species), if the number of viable organisms was stated, if  there was
>   an expiry date, and if specific health claims were made.

The results were:

> If an adequate label is defined as one that contains specific  (and
>   valid) bacterial names (genus and species), with no spelling errors
>   and a clear statement of number of viable organisms  that are
>   expected, then only 8 (32%) products were properly  labeled. If a more
>   stringent definition of an adequate label is  used, which includes a
>   requirement that the product identify  the specific bacterial strain
>   that is present, then no products  were adequately labeled.

Second, the product was tested to determine the species and quantity of probiotics present in the product. The result was:

> Only 4/15 (27%) products that had specific claims of viable organisms
>   met or exceeded their label claim.
>   ...  It is  unclear whether the products with low levels actually had
>   the  stated numbers at the time of manufacturing or whether the 
>   stated levels were never present. Regardless of whether or not the 
>   organisms died during storage or were never there is irrelevant  for
>   the patients.

However, meeting the label claim does not ensure that the product delivers a clinically significant amount of probiotics.

> For example, 1 product contained 3194% of claimed Bacillus subtilis 
>   and mixed lactic  acid bacteria, yet the label claim was very low...
>   Even though this product exceeded the label claim, the number of
>   viable organisms provided per recommended dose (1/4 to 3 tsp) would be
>   quite low and unlikely to be effective.

Additionally:

> Colonization and clinical studies involving dogs and cats, which
>   tended to use empirical dosing, have used doses of 200 million to 500
>   billion CFU/d, levels that are unachievable with most of the
>   tested products.