# How to get my cat to eat a tablet?

Tags: cats, health, eating

It's been recommended that I add a probiotic to my cat's diet to improve her digestive help - the dose is a quarter tablet twice a day.

How do people convince their cats to take their meds? I was thinking of wrapping it in ham...

Comment: If your vet did not make a specific probiotic recommendation, this question may be helpful for selection of a product: [How can I determine if a probiotic product has ingredients that will be helpful for a GI illness](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11183/how-can-i-determine-if-a-probiotic-product-has-ingredients-that-will-be-helpful)

Answer (score 1):

When I did this, the probiotic was advertised as being tasteless. I just opened the capsule and sprinkled the contents over the cat's wet food (which she considers a treat since she is mostly eating dry kibble). She showed no signs of noticing.

(She is also getting a glycosigen supplement, served the same way -- but that company actually have included some chicken flavoring.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap it in ham please consider using beef not porc because of the Aujeszky virus.

My cats love malt paste so if the pill is not too big they will not notice if I put something in there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that my cat likes cheese so if I give her a pill I use cheese.